# SSIS /C# Variables value contants backslashes how to escaping

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ssis

I have a ssis package, it will auto read the free text file by delimiter(\t).

Due the delimiter(\t) get from the database table， after passed to SSIS variable. the c# will auto add one more backslash. value = (\\t)

so if i convert variable to ToCharArray(),it will have 2 chars items.[0]="\\", [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uCVa.png)="t".This makes me unable to accurately split the file.

This is the effect I want, it can be automatically escaped to tab when it becomes char type

result = char(9) value = '\t'

```
"\t".ToCharArray();
```

2 items have been split and cannot be escaped as tab

Result:
[0] = char(92) value = '\\'
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uCVa.png) = char(116) value = 't'

```
Dts.Variables["User::ls_RepDelimiter"].Value.ToString().ToCharArray();
```

[image]

Does anyone have a good solution for this problem?

Comment: The problem is the starting point Dts.Variables["User::ls_RepDelimiter"].Value.ToString() = "\\t". That is wrong, but you can create an if or case to manage it.  
var delim = Dts.Variables["User::ls_RepDelimiter"].Value.ToString() == "\\t" ? '\t' : Dts.Variables["User::ls_RepDelimiter"].Value.ToString().ToCharArray()[0];

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option is to change what you have stored in the database. You have stored two characters `\` and `t`. Instead, you want to store the *non-printable* character tab, ASCII value 9. [CHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql) is the function that allows you to input a numeric value and get the actual character associated to it.

```
SELECT char(9) AS ActualTab, '\t' AS EncodedTab
```

Using that as the source for an Execute SQL Task and stuffing the values into Variables, I see the value shows as `\t` for my real tab and `\\t` for the encoded tab.

[image]

And it makes sense, in C-like languages, non-printable characters are displayed with a backslash before the character thus `\t` is tab, `\n` is newline and `\\` is the backslash character.

Otherwise, as @KeithL shows, a script task with a read/write variable parameter can convert the two character \t into a single character `\t`

```
Dts.Variables["User::ls_RepDelimiter"].Value = Dts.Variables["User::ls_RepDelimiter"].Value.ToString() == "\\t" ? '\t' : Dts.Variables["User::ls_RepDelimiter"].Value.ToString().ToCharArray()[0];
```

That's a one liner that evaluates whether the SSIS variable ls_RepDelimiter is equal to the two characters \t. If it is, it will use the single character `\t`, otherwise, it will strip out the first character of the string, hoping that represents what you intended to use as your delimiter within the file.

If you need to debug that, a multi-line version would be

```
string tab = "\t";
string encodedTab = "\\t";
string currentValue = Dts.Variables["User::ls_RepDelimiter"].Value.ToString();
// I am consciously using string here even though it will be a single char as I don't know what the casting rules will be for a char to string within SSIS scripting
string outValue = "";
outValue = (currentValue == encodedTab) ? tab : currentValue.ToCharArray()[0];

Dts.Variables["User::ls_RepDelimiter"].Value = currentValue;
```